# Does jQuery have a built in function to return the rootURL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I typically use the below function to return the root URL if I ever need this, but thought to ask if jQuery had a "one liner" way to do this ...

```
function getRootURL()
        {
            var baseURL = location.href;
            var rootURL = baseURL.substring(0, baseURL.indexOf('/', 7));

            // if the root url is localhost, don't add the directory as cassani doesn't use it
            if (baseURL.indexOf('localhost') == -1)
            {
                return rootURL + "/AppName/";
            } else {
                return rootURL + "/";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about

```
document.location.hostname
```

Comment: He wants the context path too.

Comment: he's adding that conditionally

Comment: var rootURL = location.hostname + (location.hostname == 'localhost' ? '/' : '/AppName/');

Comment: The context path would be here: window.location.pathname

Answer (score 9):

You can just do:

`alert(location.host)`

With **location.hostname**, you don't get the port (if there's a special port like :8080).

Answer (score 3):

To get the host, you would do this:

```
window.location.hostname
```

To get the context path:

```
window.location.pathname
```

And you can redirect the user with a querystring, like this -- preserves the hostname and port

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname + "?variable=" + theValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the hostname will only give root if the webapp is at the root of website. If its in virtual directory or a web folder then the results are incorrect. 
[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23426025/1161069) for the correct answer.
I've mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38917223/1161069) about how it can be easily achieved.