# Javascript/jQuery get root url of website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have website:
"http://www.example.com/folder1/mywebsite/subfolder/page.html"

Root of the site is: "http://www.example.com/folder1/mywebsite"

I would like to get root url of "mywebsite" dynamicly.
If I will publish this site to another place, then I will no need to change script.

For example to: "http://www.example.com/otherFolder/test/myChangedWebsite/subfolder/page.html"

I will get:
"http://www.example.com/otherFolder/test/myChangedWebsite"

I tried in "page.html" javascript:
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/otherPage.html

but this gives me only "http://www.example.com/otherPage.html".

Also I know about location.origin but this is not supported for all browser as I found that on link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_origin.asp

If it can be done with jQuery, it will be good as well.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's a function doing the same as Hawk's post above, only much, much shorter:

```
function getBaseUrl() {
    var re = new RegExp(/^.*\//);
    return re.exec(window.location.href);
}
```

Details here: [Javascript: Get base URL or root URL](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Comment: In MVC application, it gives `http://locahhost/sitename/controllername` instead of `http://locahhost/sitename`

Answer (score 8):

Use the following javascript to get the root of your url:

```
window.location.origin
```

For more details:

```
 [https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/javascript+get+root+url][1]
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

slightly shorter:

```
function getBaseUrl() {
    return window.location.href.match(/^.*\//);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your location is fixed after `mywebsite/subfolder/page.html"`

then use this

```
location.href.split("mywebsite")[0]
```

Comment: For this I need to every time specified name of "mywebsite" - example from @Hawk solved my problem, but thank you.