# Find out link is coming from external website or from the hosting which domain name belongs to. Through Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If need to find out the link is coming from external site
For example : if image link is

https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/268F292B-5DDD-4DB1-B5ABC6541A70ECDF.jpg

Then it need to display **External image**

else **image.jpg** then it needs to dispaly **internal image**

For that i have generated code like this

```
  var img= https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/268F292B-5DDD-4DB1-B5ABC6541A70ECDF.jpg;
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {

    if () {
        greeting = "External Image";
    } else {
        greeting = "Internal image";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
}
</script>
```

But i don't know the condition for making this.

Comment: There's no image in your example code...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i have added image to the code.

Comment: No, you really didn't. I think you mean `<img src="https...">`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I'm assuming your path for the external image will always remain same till `/file`

```
<script>
function myFunction() {

if ($('img').attr('src').indexOf('https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/') != -1) {
    greeting = "External Image";
} else {
    greeting = "Internal image";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle that by checking to see if the image URL contains the domain name of your application.

Borrowing from PerKristian's answer here:

[Javascript/jQuery get root url of website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425909/javascript-jquery-get-root-url-of-website/27778372)

Get the domain of your app:

```
function getBaseUrl() {
    var re = new RegExp(/^.*\//);
    return re.exec(window.location.href);
}
```

Then check if that domain exists inside your image URL:

```
if (imgUrl.toLowerCase().indexOf(domain) >= 0)
```

Putting it all together in your sample:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    if (imgUrl.toLowerCase().indexOf(getBaseUrl()) >= 0) {
        greeting = "External Image";
    } else {
       greeting = "Internal image";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
}

function getBaseUrl() {
    var re = new RegExp(/^.*\//);
    return re.exec(window.location.href);
}
</script>
```

You didn't provide where the imgUrl is coming from, so I just put a placeholder variable there with the assumption you'd either replace or assign to that variable at some point.

The only caveat to this approach is that if the image URL for some reason contained the domain name, despite being external, you would get a false positive.